# How to change the element color of the table in latex

Tags: tables, color

How to change 2021-2022 to red color in the table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
    Year 2023-2024 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
    Year 2022-2023 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text \\
    Year 2021-2022 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long   \\
    Year 2020-2021 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
    Year 2019-2020 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
    Year 2018-2019 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `\textcolor` command in order to color the text. If you want to color the background of a cell, you can use the `\cellcolor` command as shown in the following MWE. I have also replaced the `tabular` by a `tabularx` environment (since you already loaded the `tabularx` package) in order to get rid of the overfull box:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % <--- table option only needed if you want to color the background of a cell
\usepackage{tabularx} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
    Year 2023-2024 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
    Year 2022-2023 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text \\
    \textcolor{red}{Year 2021-2022} & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long   \\
    \cellcolor{red} Year 2020-2021 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
    Year 2019-2020 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
    Year 2018-2019 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```